# valgrind hangs in thread_wrapper

Tags: c, multithreading, valgrind

I'm trying to run my program in valgrind 3.10.0, but it seems to hang in **set_address_range_perms()**. The last output I get is

```
--69447:1:aspacem  allocated thread stack at 0x803c7c000 size 1064960
--69447:1:syswrap- run_a_thread_NORETURN(tid=2): pre-thread_wrapper
--69447:1:syswrap- thread_wrapper(tid=2): entry
```

Any idea how I can narrow down the problem?

Comment: Which tool? The default `memcheck` or one of the thread ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to try is to use gdb+vgdb and connect to your program which is hanging: in another window, start   gdb  
and then in gdb, do                 target remote | vgdb
You can then use various gdb commands to see what is happening e.g.   info threads;   threads apply all bt full;  ....
See 
http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver for more information about valgrind+gdb.

If the valgrind gdbserver does not react, then you will have to attach directly to valgrind, and debug the valgrind internals.

Comment: It hangs in the while loop

`threads_to_be_run = 1;
n_threads_started = 0;

void *thread_func( void *ptr )
{
    struct thread_stuff *thr = ptr;
    __sync_fetch_and_add(&n_threads_started, 1);
... 
int main() { 
  pthread_create( &thread, NULL, thread_func, ptr[i] );
 while (n_threads_started < threads_to_be_run) {
     sleep(0);
 }
`

Comment: interestingly when I run valgrind with "--fair-sched=yes" it seems to work

Comment: Yes, valgrind effectively only runs one thread at a time. In some cases such as very tight loops, the default scheduler might not let other threads run. Using the fair scheduler implies that all threads ready to run eventually run (and so, will increment n_threads_started).